# MySQL While Loop to fillup Table with incremental values where Auto-Increment is no option

Tags: mysql, if-statement, stored-procedures, while-loop, mariadb

My attempt to fill a MySQL Table with at the moment incremental values. Later on there could be changes why AUTO-INCREMENT is no solution here. **I'm working in the SWL console of phpMyAdmin**

Only the settingsOperationMixerId is AUTO-INCREMENT enabled

I tried to do a loop:

```
DELIMITER ;
CREATE PROCEDURE fill()
BEGIN
    DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE b INT DEFAULT 1; #counting upwards
    DECLARE c INT DEFAULT 1; #only 1 mixer
    DECLARE d INT DEFAULT 1; #product from 1-6


     WHILE v1 < 64 DO


        INSERT INTO `settingsoperationmixer`(`settingsOperationMixerId`,
        `settingsOperationId`, `mixerId`, `productId`) VALUES (NULL,b,c,d);

        IF d < 6 THEN SET d = d + 1;
        ELSE SET d = 1;
        END IF;

        SET b = b + 1;
        SET v1 = v1 + 1;
    END WHILE;
END;
DELIMITER ;
```

This should loop trough 63 times while the settingsOperationId will be 1-63 incremental and the productId should go from 1-6 and then start over again at 1

and get this error message:

```
Error

SQL query:

CREATE PROCEDURE fill()
BEGIN
DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 1

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
```

SQL-CODE of my Table to help resolve the issue:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.7.7
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Mar 30, 2018 at 05:13 PM
-- Server version: 10.1.30-MariaDB
-- PHP Version: 7.2.2

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `scm`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `settingsoperationmixer`
--

CREATE TABLE `settingsoperationmixer` (
  `settingsOperationMixerId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `settingsOperationId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mixerId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `productId` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `settingsoperationmixer`
--
ALTER TABLE `settingsoperationmixer`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`settingsOperationMixerId`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `settingsoperationmixer`
--
ALTER TABLE `settingsoperationmixer`
  MODIFY `settingsOperationMixerId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: Missing ; after insert , missing end if; Delimiters possibly not set.

Comment: Changed the suggested things from you P.Salmon still the same error message at the same line.

Comment: Use call p(); at the end. that was basically the missing point

Comment: First problem is with `DELIMITER ;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Corrections

```
drop procedure if exists p;
delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE p()
BEGIN DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 1; 
DECLARE a INT DEFAULT 1; #autoIncrement 
DECLARE b INT DEFAULT 1; #counting upwards 
DECLARE c INT DEFAULT 1; #only 1 mixer 
DECLARE d INT DEFAULT 1; #product from 1-6

 WHILE v1 < 64 DO
    INSERT INTO `settingsoperationmixer`(`settingsOperationMixerId`,`settingsOperationId`, `mixerId`, `productId`)  VALUES (a,b,c,d);
    IF d < 6 THEN 
        SET d = d + 1;
     ELSE 
        SET d = 1;
     end if;

    SET b = b + 1;
    SET v1 = v1 + 1;
END WHILE;
END $$
delimiter ;
```

If you want to allow auto_increment to apply then don't include it in the insert list

```
drop procedure if exists p;
delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE p()
BEGIN DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 1; 
DECLARE a INT DEFAULT 1; #autoIncrement 
DECLARE b INT DEFAULT 1; #counting upwards 
DECLARE c INT DEFAULT 1; #only 1 mixer 
DECLARE d INT DEFAULT 1; #product from 1-6

 WHILE v1 < 10 DO
    INSERT INTO `settingsoperationmixer`(`settingsOperationId`, `mixerId`, `productId`)  VALUES (b,c,d);
    IF d < 6 THEN 
        SET d = d + 1;
     ELSE 
        SET d = 1;
     end if;

    SET b = b + 1;
    SET v1 = v1 + 1;
END WHILE;
END $$
delimiter ;
drop table if exists `settingsoperationmixer`;
create table `settingsoperationmixer`
(`settingsOperationMixerId` int auto_increment primary key ,`settingsOperationId` int, `mixerId` int, `productId` int)
;
call p();
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from `settingsoperationmixer`;
+--------------------------+---------------------+---------+-----------+
| settingsOperationMixerId | settingsOperationId | mixerId | productId |
+--------------------------+---------------------+---------+-----------+
|                        1 |                   1 |       1 |         1 |
|                        2 |                   2 |       1 |         2 |
|                        3 |                   3 |       1 |         3 |
|                        4 |                   4 |       1 |         4 |
|                        5 |                   5 |       1 |         5 |
|                        6 |                   6 |       1 |         6 |
|                        7 |                   7 |       1 |         1 |
|                        8 |                   8 |       1 |         2 |
|                        9 |                   9 |       1 |         3 |
+--------------------------+---------------------+---------+-----------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Error is gone but it isn't posting anything to the DB-Table. Does this has anything to do with settingsOperationMixerId being AUTO-INCREMENT or that i use this Statement in phpMyAdmin SQL command line

Comment: changed it in the question to Value ( NULL,... ). still no error message but also no entries into the table

Comment: Is the auto_increment column a primary key?

Comment: Yes it is a primary key and just there for the table id settingsOperationMixerId

Comment: If you want `settingsOperationMixerId` to auto_increment then remove it from the insert list and remove a from the values list. If you want to override auto_increment make sure a is unique.

Comment: I removed it: VALUES (NULL,b,c,d); Furthermore, i posted the SQL command to create the same table to the question

Comment: haha, i can't stop laughing. we already had the solution like minutes ago but i didn't know that i have to use call p(); to run the function. I'm a complete beginner to MySQL. Sorry for wasting your time and thank you a lot for helping!

Answer (score 1):

a one liner in mariadb, using [Sequence storage engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/sequence-storage-engine/)

insert into t(a,b,c) select seq%6+1,seq+1,1 from seq_0_to_63;

Comment: Actually `seq_1_to_63`, since he started with 1.